# jQuery or JavaScript getting the value of .each function

Tags: jquery-ui

I have this jQuery .each function so I can traverse all the UL hmtl tags. Then I will get there id attribute. But the problems is, How can I get each value and place it to another variable so I can use it to .sortable UI function. Here is my code:

```
jQuery('.b ul').each(function(){
  jQuery(this).attr('id');
});
```

example: the output of the .each function when I do alert is "0 1 2". How can I place it to another variable? So it would be use in:

```
jQuery(variable here).sortable(){ });
```

The code above will get the ID attribute. Anyone who can help?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the ID's at all. You can provide jQuery's `$()` function with more than just ID's:

```
$('.b ul').sortable();
```

Or if you are using multiple libraries (jQuery, MooTools, etc.):

```
jQuery('.b ul').sortable();
```

Comment: how can I restrict the sortable be connected to other div? example Div1 will be pass to Div2 and Div2 cannot pass to Div1

Comment: This might work: `$('.b ul').sortable({containment: $(this)});`.

Answer (score 1):

Any of these should work

Save the jquery array to a variable to act on later:

```
var $lists = $(".b ul")
$lists.sortable()
```

Act on the selector directly:

```
$(".b ul").sortable()
```

Don't do this:

```
var ids = []
$(".b ul").each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id")
  ids.push(id)
})
var selector = "#" + ids.join(", #")
$(selector).sortable()
```

Comment: how can I restrict the sortable be connected to other div? example Div1 will be pass to Div2 and Div2 cannot pass to Div1

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to drag and drop between two jQuery UI Sortable DIVs, similar to this explanation?:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

Look at the explanation of the **connectWith option** for how to connect two lists together:
`$( ".selector" ).sortable({ connectWith: '.otherlist' });`